# Magento2: understanding ui_component xml tags

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

In Magento 2 `ui_component` xml files are used to show grid/forms in admin. The model collection which  will be used by the grid will be configured in `di.xml` as mentioned here

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sample_demolist_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Genmato\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Now in the ui_component xml file arguments will be mentioned as below

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sample_demolist_listing.sample_demolist_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sample_demolist_listing.sample_demolist_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
 <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">sample_demolist_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Item</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

1. What does `<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">` do?
2. What is the usages of tags `js_config`, `provider`, `deps`, `spinner`, `class`, `url` ? 
 If I can get some reference links/tutorials which explains all these tags will be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look in di.xml

> \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory

class define one object $collections

```
public function __construct(
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManagerInterface,
    array $collections = []
) {
    $this->collections = $collections;  <==== Injection in consturctor
    $this->objectManager = $objectManagerInterface;
}
```

How magento can get this value

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::create()
```

This  method will get all arugments data in argument node

Comment: That helps. Can you share some thoughts on question 2?

Comment: In magento 2 core team have created some Collector, Converter. It used to collect all data from your xml. All of them will be merge and spit to array for each attributes
You can see more in \Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\ folder
Magento\module-ui\Model\Manager.php::prepareData()

Comment: Hi Mrtuvn , i need suggestion on this error as to how to debug this:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161957/magento-2-localizedexception-more-than-one-node-matching-the-query-error-in-d