# Magento 2 : Can a single UI Component node have more than one collection?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 - Is it a good practice to give 2 collections or more in my UI Component tag as shown :

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="brand_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">HBPlus\Brand\Model\ResourceModel\Brand\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="group_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">HBPlus\Brand\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Grid\Collection</item> <!--Can this be given? -->
        </argument> 
    </arguments>
</type>
```

I had separated out the collections under the same node as below for which i used to get this error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'More than one node matching the query: /config/type[@name='Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory']' in /var/www/html/Namespace/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 276**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="brand_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">HM\Brand\Model\ResourceModel\Brand\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="group_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">HM\Brand\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: I am not sure about this. You can seperate collection ui. It works without problem. Check your ui listing/form config first

Comment: Where do i check this form config, and if i follow the 2nd snippet in my answer i get the error  as described: More than one node matching the query

Comment: config locate in module_dir/view/area/ui-component Make sure all xml tags are valid

Comment: Ok will cross check, as of now have included the collections under the same  Ui component tag , thanks for the file path